# How to determine line type and color for two different variables for graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question concerns an issue with producing a graph in R:

I have data where I had one variable that stated the treatment, and whether it was with or without additives (e.g. control_with). Now I want to make a line graph where the color of the line was based on treatment and the line type (solid/dashed) was based on additives. This seemed hard to do when these were combined in a single variable so I split them into 2 variables: 'Treatment' and 'Additives'. I want to plot my data and group them by these 2 variables.

I have tried using this:

`ggplot(cricketcomp, aes(x = Week, y = Average_weight, group = Treatment, Additives)) + geom_line(aes(linetype = Additives, color = Treatment))+ geom_point(aes(color = Treatment))+ theme(legend.position = "top")`

But it returned the error message: Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line

I think maybe it cannot differentiate between control_with and control_without anymore, since now both would have the 'Treatment' control.

How do I make the graph where I can group the data in both 'Treatment' and 'Additives'?

Comment: Try with `group = interaction(Treatment, Additives)`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
df <- tibble(
        Treatment=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=4),
        Additives=rep(c("Yes", "No"), each=2, times=2),
        X=rep(c(0, 1), times=4),
        Y=c(0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.6, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1)
      )
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y, colour=Treatment)) +
         geom_line(aes(linetype=Additives)) +
         geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: yes, but then it gives me the error that I mentioned

Comment: Then I cannot reproduce your problem. My code creates the plot I have posted.